# Highlighting keywords in text

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that has one table with a varchar(1000) field that contains a bunch of user input about books.  I have another table that contains a bunch of keywords.  When I render the user's info about the books, I want to highlight (or eventually create a hyperlink) on these keywords.  I'm looking for suggestions on the most efficient method for scanning through the text and matching the keywords up.  I wasn't sure if there's a way to do it right in SQL or it it needs to be in the code.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the user entered keywords foreign keys to a master keyword table? What is the schema of the two tables?

Comment: 1)put [user input about book] into foreach string array[]
2)compare each string with the keyword and render it become hyperlink
3)check the respond time for analysis result

Comment: I think this must be done through code only rather SQL..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing it in code. It's business logic, and besides doing so lightens the load in the database - so if the database is in a machine other than the servers running your app, you don't hog that machine's resources.

I think regex would do the trick for you - it's the most efficient method of text matching ever invented, and the internal implementation in most technologies (not only .NET) is pretty much the best you can get. If you try to come up with something else you'll at best be reinventing the wheel.

So I'd do this: place every keyword in a hashtable or dictionary - which has the bonus of cutting off duplicates, then iterate through that. Then for each match on of the keyword in the main text, you can get the first and last index of the match and wrap that with markup for the highlight and the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick LINQPad program that I wrote up that will replace values in a string with dictionary values that match up on the keys.  Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Side Note: I agree with everyone else that you should be doing this in the application layer for a variety of reasons.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> links = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    links.Add("awesome", "link-to-awesome");
    links.Add("okay", "link-to-okay");

    string text = "This is some text about an okay book review of an otherwise awesome book.";

    string result = links.Aggregate(text, (current, kvp) => current.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
    text.Dump();
    result.Dump();
}
```

Results:

```
This is some text about an okay book review of an otherwise awesome book. 
This is some text about an link-to-okay book review of an otherwise link-to-awesome book.
```

Edit: This isn't a perfect example.  You'd have to strip out punctuation and what-not for a final version.  Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

If the links are fixed then personally I would do this when WRITING to the DB as it will only be done once, then it required no extra effort to display.